# construct Issue in Codeigniter 3.1.2

Tags: php, codeigniter

We have recently updated to Codeigniter 3.1.2 and got one issue.

We have call one controller file to anther controller file using below code.

First Controller :

---

```
$this->load->library('../controllers/secondcontroller');
$this->secondcontroller->functionName();
```

Second Controller :

---

```
class Secondcontroller extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->helper(array('form','url','file'));
```

It was working fine in last version but i have checked that now it not working Codeigniter 3.1.2

Could you please help to change correct code based on version.

Thanks in Advance .

Comment: What is the error message you get? As you are extending `CI_Controller` you may access `$this->` as `$this->load->helper(array('form','url','file'));`

Comment: Codeigniter supports MVC, not HierarchicalMVC as you are trying to do here. Maybe you can achieve a dirty solution, but sooner or later your application will fail. Use helpers and libraries if you can abstract the functions out of the controller.

You can also extend the CI_Controller and place there some general functions that need access to the instance.

Comment: You can not call controller with in controller in normal MVC you should use HMVC https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads?tab=branches

Comment: @Dacklf There is a HMVC plug in as my link above